# Array not filtering/mapping with useParams()

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to be able to display more info on a product when you click on said product. The correct id is shown when product is clicked, but no image is mapped to product/:id it's just an empty div.
Thanks!

//data I'm filtering/mapping

```
const products = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Dangle Links',
    image: '/images/danglelinkgreen.jpg',
    description: 'Handmade Clay Earings.',
    price: 30.00,
    inStock: true,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Abstract Links',
    image: '/images/abstractlink.jpg',
    description: 'Handmade Clay Earings.',
    price: 30.00,
    inStock: true,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Arches',
    image: '/images/arches2.jpg',
    description: 'Handmade Clay Earings.',
    price: 30.00,
    inStock: true,
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: 'String Of Pearls',
    image: '/images/stringofpearls1.jpg',
    description: 'Handmade Clay Earings.',
    price: 37.00,
    inStock: true,
  },
]

export default products;
```

//How I'm using useParams

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link, useParams } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Row, Col, Image, ListGroup, Card, Button } from 'react-bootstrap'
import products from '../products'
import Product from '../components/Product'


const ProductScreen = () => {
    const { id } = useParams()
  
    return (
    <>
          <Link className='btn btn-light my-3' to='/'>
              GO BACK
          </Link>
              <div>
              <Row>
                <Col md={8}>
                {products.filter(product => product.id === id).map((product) => (
                      <div>
                          <Image src={product.image} alt={product.name} />
                      </div>
                ))}
                </Col>
                <Col md={4}></Col>
               </Row>
              </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default ProductScreen
```

//App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Container } from 'react-bootstrap';
import Header from './components/Header';
import Footer from './components/Footer';
import Review from './components/Review'
import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen';
import ProductScreen from './screens/ProductScreen';
import products from './products'




const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Header />
      <main className='py-3'>
        <Container>
          <Route exact path='/'>
            <HomeScreen />
          </Route>
                 
          <Route path='/product/:id'>
            <ProductScreen product={products}/>
          </Route>
        </Container> 
      </main>
      <Review />  
      <Footer />
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Not sure if it matters, but Product component is nested in HomeScreen.js instead of directly to App.js, like so..

//Product.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Card } from 'react-bootstrap'



const Product = ({ product }) => {
  return (
    <Card className='my-3 p-3 rounded'>
      <Link to={`/product/${product.id}`}>
        <Card.Img src={product.image} variant='top' />
      </Link> 

      <Card.Body>
        <Link to={`/product/${product.id}`}>
        <Card.Title as='div'><strong>{product.name}</strong></Card.Title>
        </Link> 

        <Card.Text as='h3'>
              ${product.price}
        </Card.Text>
      </Card.Body>   
    </Card>
  )
}

export default Product
```

//HomeScreen

```
import React from 'react'
import products from '../products'
import Product from '../components/Product'
import { Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap'

const HomeScreen = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Jewelry</h1>
      <Row>
        {products.map((product) => (
          <Col sm={12} md={6} lg={4} xl={3}>
            <Product product={product} />
          </Col>
        ))}
      </Row> 
    </>
  )
}

export default HomeScreen
```

Comment: Instead of setting the `product.image` attribute you've use the `product.price` attribute. I think that's the problem.

Comment: sorry, I copied the text after trying to see if any property would map through.

Comment: If you tried the `image` attribute and it didn't work, it means that it's a problem with the backend that should receive that request, not here.

Comment: I encountered a similar problem before i has to prefix the url with `http://localhost/` to solve it, this happened because i had my front end and back end running on different servers during development.

Comment: You may be able to know the problem more by checking developer tools > network tab, , find the request for the images and check the error message there.

Comment: aim97 I'm not seeing any errors pertaining to the images request. Actually I'm not even seeing a request. Also adding http:// didn't do anything. Thank you though!

Comment: @mikecastro you may want try moving your code into a [codesandbox](http://codesandbox.com/) that way you can test it in an isolated environment which you can share with everyone to be on the same page.

Comment: Got it figured out. 'product.id === id' id was a string type being compared to product.id which is a number. I just wrapped parseInt(id) and it worked! Not sure if that's the right way to solve it or not. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

in order to display the image the `src` attribute of the image tag should hold the image url not the product price.

```js
{products.filter(product => product.id === id).map((product) => (
      <div>
          <Image src={product.image} alt={product.name} />
      </div>
))}
```

You may also consider using `Array.find` instead of `filter` and `map`, since you are working with a single product, load that single product outside jsx code

```js
product = product.find(id => product.id === id);
```

then use `product` in the display directly.